# Bash script to automate file moving

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, download, automation

In Windows, I had a batch file full of if statements to move files around after download.  For example, `xmen` is moved to the `/movies/xmen` folder.

I have found something similar to what I'm looking for here: [SH script to move files from one dir to another depending on the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573815/sh-script-to-move-files-from-one-dir-to-another-depending-on-the-filename#)

But for whatever reason it is not working in Ubuntu 15.10.  It gets the filename and that part processes, but the actual moving doesn't work.  It just comes back saying it doesn't know what to do with the file (it shows the results of the variable however).

Here is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "/media/james/Media/downloads/"
for filename in *; do
# this syntax emits the value in lowercase: ${var,,*}  (bash version 4)
case "${filename,,*}" in
  *.ini) : ;;
  *.exe) : ;;
  *.bat) : ;;
  *.zip) : ;;
  *.iso) : ;;
  *.sh) : ;;
  *.*qB) : ;;
  *.*jpg) : ;;
  tc.*)    mv "$filename" "/media/plexdocu/" ;;
  nhk.*)    mv "$filename" "/media/plexdocu/" ;;
  itv.*)    mv "$filename" "/media/plexdocu/" ;;
  *) echo "don't know where to put $filename";;
  esac
done
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That works for me. What is your exact input and output? What files do you try to move?

Comment: That's working for me too. Though, you'll get "don't know where to put $filename" for the files that do not match any of the optional patterns inside the case statement. I suggest that you'll give it another test and create a directory in which you'll have only files that match one or more of the patterns. That's what I did right now on my PC and it's working just fine. As a side note: I would `for filename in /media/james/Media/downloads/*; do` instead, which will also prevent option-like files, to affect on the `mv` command. You might also want to modify `mv` to mv -- "$filename" whatever.

Comment: I have a file called ITV.Worlds.greatest.jobs.mp4.  It finds the file and lists it as 'dont know where to put it', but isn't being moved.  I'm on my Windows partition atm, so I haven't made any modifications, but I will and report back soon.

Comment: I think that converting the filename in lowercase (comment says bash version 4)  failed. You can test it by changing `itv.*)` into `ITV.*)` or just `echo "Lowercase file ${filename,,*}"` befire the line starting with `case`. When this is the case, you can try to fix with `case $(echo $filename | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]') in`

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it (adding the -- to mv and changing the filename in directory.  It also helps if I have the destination directory with the correct case.  I keep forgetting that in linux.

IDK if i can ask this here, but in the same code, im filtering out certain filetypes.  How would I filter out directories too?

thanks again :)